# Making a webpage load part way down the page

Tags: javascript, html

So I've done some Googling but it hasn't helped. What I want is for the visible portion of the page to load part way down the actual page, so that when a user goes to the site they can immediately scroll *up* to reveal more of the page.

I hope that's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `scrollBy` function:

```
function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 200);
}
window.onload = pageScroll;
```

Source:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollby.asp

Answer (score 2):

I would use a named anchor, like `<a name="startingPoint"></a>` at the point on your page where you want users to start out, then jump to it like this as soon as the page loads:

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.location.hash = "startingPoint";
}
```